# Replot the same data point multiple times before continuing in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, interpolation

If I have the following code :

```
for t=1:length(s)  % s is a struct with over 1000 entries
  if s(t).BOX==0
    a(t,:)=0;
    elseif s(t).BOX==1
    a(t,:)=100;
  end
  if s(t).BOX==2
    b(t,:)=150;
    elseif s(t).BOX==3
    b(t,:)=170;
  end
  .
  .
  .

end
plot(a)
plot(b)
plot(c)
```

What I want to accomplish :

```
for n=1:length(s)

Plot the data point of a(n) at t=0, t=1, t=2
then
Plot the data point of b(n) at t=3, t=4, t=5
.
.
.
etc
```

So basically, each data point will be plotted at 3 values of `t` before moving to the next point.

How can I achieve that ?

**EDIT**

Something like this :

[image]

Comment: not sure if this is what you want to do, but try to prepend the arrays with `NaN` values as needed. This will make the plots look like shifted in time. If you want to repeat some values, replicate them so that: `[1 2 3]` becomes `[1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3]`

Comment: Well `a(t,:)` depends on `t`, so making `t` equal to more than one value at the same time will provide an unwanted output. I think I misunderstood what you meant. Maybe add it as a potential answer below ?

Comment: truth is I still don't fully get the code you posted, hence I only wrote a comment. Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Basically, I want to have something like this (check question, updated)

Comment: Two questions: firstly, can you add a sample of the code where you allocate `a, b, etc.`, and secondly: you do or do not want to plot the entire time series for each of your variables `a, b, etc.`? From your question it kind of sounds like you want to plot 3 from `a`, skipping 3 from `b, c, etc.`, then plot 3 from `b`, skipping all the others from `a, c, etc.`...

Comment: @wakjah No no, sorry that it doesn't sound clear, I tried to make it as clear as possible. I want to plot the same data point 3 times every single time it plots a point, before moving on to a different data point. So 3 from `a`, then 3 from `b`, then 3 from `c` etc. -- repeat

Comment: @wakjah I updated the question, now i know why it doesn't look clear i'm using `t` to plot at the x-axis as well as gathering info from struct `s` -- Fixed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, and assuming `a` is a vector, you could do something like

```
% Your for loop comes before this

nVarsToPlot = 4;
nRepeatsPerPoint = 3;
t = repmat(linspace(1, nRepeatsPerPoint * length(s), nRepeatsPerPoint * length(s))', 1, nVarsToPlot);
genMat = @(x)repmat(x(:)', nRepeatsPerPoint, 1);
aMat = genMat(a); bMat = genMat(b); cMat = genMat(c); dMat = genMat(d);
abcPlot = [aMat(:) bMat(:) cMat(:) dMat(:)];
plot(t, abcPlot);
```

I'm a bit unclear on exactly what values you want your `t` to contain, but you essentially need a vector 3 times the length of `s`. You can then generate the correct data matrix by copying your `[Nx1]` vectors (`a, b, c, etc.`) three times (after transposing them to row vectors) each and stacking the whole lot into matrix, then transforming it to a vector with `(:)` which should come out in the right order as long as the matrix is constructed correctly.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I would like to keep `a b c` as each data point has various IF statements before choosing the correct `r` value. Is there a way I can implement what I want without making the code too complex ?

Comment: What size are `a, b, c` in each iteration? The above will only work if they are scalars...

Comment: Answer updated - does this do what you're expecting? Or not quite because you need all the variables `a, b, c, etc.` on the same plot?

Comment: Do I put this after the for loop or inside it ?

Comment: After. I modified it slightly as well; I think it should be what you're after now.

Comment: Well it is plotting, but check how different they look https://dl.dropbox.com/u/695335/plot.png  -- If each data point is plotted at 3 values of t each, wouldn't the plot extend to more than 250 ?

Comment: Ah, so you DO want to plot them separately, and your maximum value of `t` SHOULD be multiplied by the number of repeats. Answer updated (again). Edit: answer updated for 4 variables, too :)

Comment: Sorry for being so unclear haha ... Thank you that did the trick. I have 4 variables, I tried adding this for `d` but I get : `Error using horzcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.` any idea why ?

Comment: I tried the update you did before asking. Even the update you just added gives me the same error.

Comment: `d` must not be the same size as `a`, `b`, and `c`.

Comment: yes you're right, I just checked size(d) and its not consistent with a b and c. I'll to try to figure that out. Thanks for helping me :) Can you please provide a brief explanation to how the code is working compared to my method ? would love to learn :)

Comment: Would you know how to create a legend with colors of my choice ?